# How to make `sbt test` to run tests in main project and all subprojects (or some selected set)

Tags: scala, testing, configuration, sbt

I have a main project and a few subprojects. When I want to run tests, currently I have to do `sbt test` and `sbt subProjectName/test`. Is there any way of making sbt run all tests or for example all tests in the main project and one of the subprojects.

I am using Build.scala configurations, but can't find a way of setting this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Therefore `sbt` supports `aggregate`.

for in depth details read: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html#aggregation

In given example all commands  at `mainProject` will also be run on `other-project`. 
So running `mainProject/test` will also run `otherProject/test`.
If `mainProject` is your base project `test` will be enough.

in `build.sbt`

```
lazy val mainProject = 
   (project in file("."))
   .aggregate(otherProject)

lazy val otherProject = (project in file("other-project"))
```