# Test reporter for multi-project sbt

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

I have a `build.sbt` with about two dozens of project having hundreds of test.  I would like a test reporter that can aggregate tests from all projects in `build.sbt` into a single table, so I don't have to look into every project to see test results.

Any solution, either a custom test listener or junit-style xml-file aggregation would work for me.

I would the reporter do both:

- display a list of tests with statuses in the console output of `sbt test` and
- have the same report in a single file.

The main goal it to have a **single report** for all projects in `build.sbt`.

Thank you

Comment: What happens if you run `test` in root project? Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32884308/how-to-make-sbt-test-to-run-tests-in-main-project-and-all-subprojects-or-some. You should be able to just configure your unit testing framework settings in SBT to output to some XML report. Привет кстати :)

Comment: Привет.  When I run `sbt test` it runs test in all projects and reports test results after each project.  So I get 100 screens to scroll up and look for results.